# Executing Python script via Laravel controller

Tags: python, laravel

It may be a simple question but i could not find a solution that works for me properly. So i want to start a python skript via a controller in laravel. So far i tried exec(), shell_exec() and this as well:

```
$cmd = "py pathtoSkript/example.py";

  if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
      pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
  }
  else {
      exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
  }
```

My python Version is: `Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (I`

When the process is started it should only run the skript like you type:

`py yourPath/example.py` in the windows shell. shell_exec() in my case feezes the current session and exec dont work. The Script works fine when i execute it via pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Symfony Process https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

**Installation**

```
 composer require symfony/process
```

**Usage**

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['py pathtoSkript/example.py']);
// or $process = new Process(['python', 'pathtoSkript/example.py']);

try {
    $process->mustRun();

    echo $process->getOutput();
} catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
 $command = escapeshellcmd('py pathtoSkript/example.py');
 $output = shell_exec($command);
 $output;
```

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php